# Spring boot, is it safe to use Spring MVC and Jersey together

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

Is it safe, or even possible, to use *Jersey* and *Spring MVC* together via Spring boot starters? I realize Jersey registers it's own servlet (mapped to /* with default configuration) to handle requests, where as Spring MVC registers it's dispatcher servlet (mapped to / with default configuration).

Is it possible and safe to configure Jersey servlet to handle request under the */api* path, where as Spring MVC would still handle all other requests, or would this lead to conflicts/instability, or considered as a bad design solution?

Comment: Jersey can also use a `Filter`. And why wouldn't it be safe? Also do you really want 2 frameworks for web handling? Why not simply use spring mvc for your JSON/ marshaling etc. as well.

Comment: Yes obviously it is safe and will work fine. But why you need this, I am using this combination for so long it works fine but I personally recommend you to use one framework. You can have multiple dispatchers for Spring and Jersey.

Comment: I found this question and the reason I was searching is because I was using Spring Boot with Jersey for my application but now I want to add Actuator.  Actuator relies on MVC, so now I need to include both in my application.

So I think there's a valid use case to have both.